# Find total with only the first iteration from relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In this scenario I have a `Ticket` model and a `TicketReply` model.

I can grab all replies to a ticket with `$ticket->replies`.

Considering status 1 or 3 of a ticket or reply means its state is open/unresolved, this is how I currently find the total of tickets open the **Eloquent** way.

```
$tickets = Ticket::all();

$tickets_open = 0;

foreach($tickets as $t)
{
    $tickets_open++;

    if(($t->replies()->first()->status == 2) || ($t->status == 2))
    {
        $tickets_open--;
    }
}

return $tickets_open;
```

**Is there a more efficient way of doing this with *Eloquent*?**

Since as it is a query will run for each iteration.

If there is not, I can convert `$tickets` to an array and iterate it.

**Update:**

`$t->replies()->first()->status` was causing the `1+N` with or without eager loading.

I changed to `$t->replies->first()->status` and `1+N` is gone. A rookie mistake I believe.

Comment: Question, why not just calculate open tickets in an SQL query? a fancy feature in a framework wont outpace simplicity...

Comment: I don't know how to consider only the latest reply of the ticket.

Comment: As you can see in `$t->replies()->first()->status`. The replies relationship has an order by updated_at desc.

Comment: Can't you just use `$open = Reply::where('status', 2)->count()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) to reduce the number of queries.

```
$tickets = Ticket::with('replies')->get();
```

Doing this, instead of running `1+N` queries, you will end up running two SQL queries:

```
select * from Tickets

select * from TicketReplies where ticket_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

Comment: I need to consider only the latest reply from the ticket, as you can see in `$t->replies()->first()->status`. The replies relationship has an order by updated_at desc.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's a bit confusing to me but I believe you may try something like this:

```
$openTickets = Reply::where('status', 2)->count();
```

Also maybe something like this:

```
$tickets = Ticket::whereHas('replies', function($query) {
    $query->where('status', 2);
})->with('replies')->get();
```

Then count:

```
$t = 0;
$tickets->fetch('replies')->each(function($i) use (&$t){
    $t += count($i);
});
dd($t); // total
```

I could be wrong but I guessed it could be done like this.

*P/S:Please let me know the update.*

Comment: When you say `it's a bit confusing to me`, made me realize I should never have more than one reply open for a ticket. Only the latest reply should be open when is the case.

Comment: If you still curious, `->fetch('replies')->each(function($i)` returns all replies, not only the latest reply from a ticket.